# How to have multi orders in includes query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: `Question` and `Answer`. Question - Answers relationship is `1-n`

Both my question and answer have `order` attribute and now I need to list questions with their answers in order.

Sth like:

```
Question.includes(:answers).order(questions: {order: :asc}, answers: {order: :asc})
```

Any help is highly approciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came with a solution

```
@questions = Question
               .includes(:answers)
               .includes(:categories)
               .order('questions.order desc', 'answers.order desc').all
```

Read more [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an order on the `has_many` in your model.

```
# app/models/question.rb
# This will order answers by date, you presumably want something else
has_many :answers, -> { order(date: :desc) }
```